# Xcode and the path nightmare

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have this project called engine.xcodeproj embedded inside another project myApp.

This engine has to get an value from MainViewController.h that is the header of a class of the application, outside the scope of the engine.xcodeproj.

How do I make all app main paths visible to embedded projects!

I am using Xcode 5 and compiling for iOS 6.

I have answered this before on SO, but the answers to those questions are not solving this case...

see picture:

[image]

thanks.

Comment: You're doing it backwards. Normally an Xcode project should be able to build itself, with no external dependencies. If your `engine` project depends on a header file in the outer `MyApp` project, then it can't build by itself. Why are you using separate projects at all?

Comment: because the idea is to have this engine to be used by several apps. This is the only case that the engine must access the main class. It all happens when the user quits using the module and wants to return to the main menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uhm, this is what is called spaghetti code.

It would be better to define a protocol in the Engine project, which your view controller can implement, and then pass an `id<Protocol>` to the engine. This creates an abstraction between the two projects while defining a strong language (API) between them. You mention you wish to use the Engine project in several apps - this is your best solution.

In Engine project:

```
@protocol MyAPIProtocol

@required

//Define here the actions you want to perform/get from the data source.
- (CGFloat)floatValue;
- (UITextView*)textView;
- (void)displayAlertWithMessage:(NSString*)message;

@end
```

Now, your Rocket class should have a property defined like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyAPIProtocol> dataSource; //Whatever name you need, of course
```

Now in your apps that use this Engine project:

```
#import "MyAPIProtocol.h"

@interface MainViewController () <MyAPIProtocol>
@end

@implementation MainViewController

...

//Implement the protocol
- (CGFloat)floatValue
{
    return 123.0f;
}

- (UITextView*)textView
{
    return self.textView;
}

- (void)displayAlertWithMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    //...
}

@end
```

The result is that the Engine project is self-contained, and does not need to know the implementation of `MainViewController`. It just knows that it has a `dataSource` property which can satisfy all its needs.

Now, when you have your Engine object ready in your MainViewController, you should set its data source by:

`self.engine.dataSource = self;`

Comment: I fixed the protocol definition. Did you `#import` the .h file of where you defined the protocol? You should import it in `MainViewController`.

Comment: @RubberDuck No no, it's not black magic. You declare a method in the protocol and implement in the MainViewController. Don't forget to set the data source: `engine.dataSource = self;`. Now, on the engine, you just call `[self.dataSource objectIneed];` and it will go to the implementation.

And why are you deleting your comments?

Comment: where do I set engine.dataSource = self; ? You don't mention it on your answer!

Comment: Appended to the answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for answering you that much. Using protocols is something that is not on my blood stream... For now it is working and it is black magic to me. I am reading some docs about protocols to understand that definitively.